# How to use Type interface to pass while class initialization of generic<T>?

Tags: java, android

We are parsing okhttp response objects using GSON.

In order to allow a generic parsing logic, We had opened to pass a type of response using setType(Type type) and now using below code to parse all responses.

```
Object mResponse = mGson.fromJson(response.body().string(), mType);
```

As this code is not open for a change I have extended this class and overridden the parse response method. I have also created a new class called MyRespose and want to initialize with whatever type is passed in setType method so that the consumers are returned the object of what type they have passed instead of an instance of Object class.

```
public class MyResponse<T> {

    private int mStatus;

    private T mResponseData;

    public MyResponse(int status, T responseBody) {
        this.mStatus = status;
        mResponseData = responseBody;
    }

    public MyResponse(T responseBody) {
        mResponseData = responseBody;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return mStatus;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.mStatus = status;
    }

    public T getResponseData() {
        return mResponseData;
    }

    public void setResponseData(T responseData) {
        mResponseData = responseData;
    }
}
```

How can I use the Type(interface) to pass as  so that the when someone calls getResponseData it return the object of type which is passed in setType instead of a generic Object ?

Something like

```
Object mResponse = mGson.fromJson(response.body().string(), mType);

mMyResponse = new MyResponse<???>(response.code(), mResponse );
```

How can i use mType to pass at place of "???"

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can make use of `TypeToken` here. Its included in Gson and should go like this.

```
Type responseType = new TypeToken<MyResponse<XYZ>>() {}.getType();

gson.fromJson(json, responseType);
```

You can read further on this [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)

Comment: This is what I am doing exactly for parsing TypeToken<T> or Type mType is user passed something, I have the type object now how can build my MyResponse<T> object using the responseType or mType(in my case). what is XYZ here?

Comment: XYZ is the class you would pass as Type parameter.

Comment: Yes that is correct but I want to determine that from responseType. consider there is a method says setResponseType(Type type). Now you have type how you can build MyResponse using that type, and return the object of MyResponse<Type_Here> with that type?